# Is the default IServiceProvider in ASP.NET Core thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-core

I'm building a small ASP.NET Core app that also has a bunch of separate business logic that runs in its own thread. I was already using a `IServiceProvider` in the side program, so when I found out that ASP.NET Core also uses its own `IServiceProvider`, so I thought I could re-use only a single instance.

Now the question is, is the `IServiceProvider` that the web host uses thread safe? My setup basically looks like this

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

Task.Run(() => {
  // here I access the IServiceProvider via `host.Services`
  new Foo(host.Services).Run();
});

host.Run();
```

Answer (score 9):

[The default service provider implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/DI/ServiceProvider.cs). You can see services factories are stored in [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/DI/ServiceProvider.cs#L33) and [building an expression for creating service object](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/DI/ServiceProvider.cs#L87) is executed in separate thread except the first one. And I am sure this expression is also thread-safe (likely stateless). So the default `ServiceProvider` is thread-safe.

Comment: While the link may answer the question you should include a snippet of the code the shows what it is you are trying to prove.