# Is the CreateScope from IServiceProvider thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, thread-safety, service-provider

I've got a code snippet that looks a bit like this:

```cs
// Program.cs
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
services.AddSingleton<SingletonService>();
```

```cs
// SingletonService.cs
public class SingletonService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public SingletonService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    public bool DoSomething(Foo foo)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();

        service.Data = foo;
        return service.ProcessData();
    }
}
```

Is the DoSomething method thread-safe in this context, considering the shared _serviceProvider and the use of CreateScope?

I couldn't find any information about this in the docs.

Comment: Assuming you're asking about the default implementation, does this answer your question? [Is the default IServiceProvider in ASP.NET Core thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544907/is-the-default-iserviceprovider-in-asp-net-core-thread-safe)

Comment: @fredrik Yes, thank you.